# Excel VBA code - changing legends

Tags: excel, vba

Chart using slicer selection:

[image]

Chart without slicer selection:

[image]

I have done these graphics using two different pivot tables but I had to do some calculations field then I have become it on a static table to make it! The graphic number 2 is the one that I am not using a specific slicer selection so the legend is right. However when I use a specific slicer selection the legend stay as you can see on the graphic number with the traces but without text. Is there any VBA code that I could use in order to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Here you can find help with code you have already made, nobody will do the job for you from scratch. Try to do something, show us what you have done and we will improve from there

Comment: - Sub mudar_range_price()

- Dim sht As Worksheet
- Set sht = Worksheets("price_pivot")
- Sheets("price_pivot").Activate

- Dim i As Long
- Dim lastcol As Long


- For i = 1 To Columns.Count

    - If Cells(129, i + 1).Text = "-" Then
       - lastcol = i
        - i = 16384
     - End If

- Next i


- Sheets("price").Activate
- ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("price").Activate
        -  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
         - ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range(sht.Cells(129, 1), sht.Cells(141, lastcol))

- End Sub()

 - Its working now! Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. I often find the answer to my questions just by spending time to write the question. By the time the question is well written... the answer is there. If your code works you can answer to your own question instead of adding it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Sub mudar_range_price()
 - Dim sht As Worksheet 
- Set sht = Worksheets("price_pivot") - Sheets("price_pivot").Activate 
- Dim i As Long 
- Dim lastcol As Long 
- For i = 1 To Columns.Count 
- If Cells(129, i + 1).Text = "-" Then 
- lastcol = i 
- i = 16384 
- End If 
- Next i - Sheets("price").Activate
 - ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("price").Activate  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select 
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range(sht.Cells(129, 1), sht.Cells(141, lastcol)) - End Sub()